# SQLite order of attached databases matters?

Tags: debugging, sqlite, common-table-expression

I am attaching 2 databases, call them A and B, to an inmemory instance of SQLite.
A is older and has a View called MAINVIEW for example.
B is a newer, has the same View called the same way MAINVIEW only that is built now with CTE (newer SQLite version that let me do that instead of subselects)

If I attach A first and B second, and I try to dump B.MAINVIEW it comes out empty, A.MAINVIEW comes out as expected.
If I attach B first and A second, both dumps come out as expected, and the rest of fancy usage I use them for, view of views and joins and sorts.

Abstract description, I know, but not much code I can put in as them DBs are built through bash+sqlite and that is not the nicest thing to put on and actually be clear.

Anyone encountered this behavior yet.

Any tips on how can I debug this in a better way (can't understand much out of .eqp on dumps that it is doing but I can post on request for anyone that decyphers them properly)

Old DB(s) have been created with SQLite 3.7.10
New DB(s) have been created with SQLite 3.15.2

Simplified example:

```sql
.databases  
.load ./lib/libsqlitefunctions.so  
DETACH DATABASE '103nd10';  
DETACH DATABASE '103nd14';  
ATTACH DATABASE '/sp001fe1/proj/5297/103nd10/SAVE/4D/sqlite/103nd10.db' AS '103nd10';
ATTACH DATABASE '/sp001fe1/tpa/103nd14/DATA/SQLite/103nd14.db' AS '103nd14';
.tables
CREATE TEMP VIEW IF NOT EXISTS vInteractive AS
    SELECT m0tvSP.ID AS SP_ID 
    FROM "103nd10".vSP AS btvSP 
    INNER JOIN "103nd14".vSP AS m0tvSP ON m0tvSP.ID == btvSP.ID;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vInteractive;
```

Output after .database:

> seq  name             file
>
> ---
>
> 0    main
>   2    103nd14          /sp001fe1/tpa/103nd14/DATA/SQLite/103nd14.db
>   3    103nd10          /sp001fe1/proj/5297/103nd10/SAVE/4D/sqlite/103nd10.db

Output after .tables:

> 103nd10.Edit_RCV                   103nd10.vSP_port
>      ...
>      103nd10.vPerimeter_SP              103nd14.vSP
>      ...
>      103nd10.vResponse                  103nd14.vWeekly
>      103nd10.vSP

Line count of the view:

> COUNT(*)
>   0

If I switch the ATTACH DATABASES around, the Line count becomes:

> COUNT(*)
>   24340

Even if I only try to dump the **103nd14.vSP** view I get 0 using the first order.
That is how I identified the problem being with the 103nd14 databases and its view that is using CTEs.

Comment: So you have tables with the same name in both DBs?

Comment: Afirmative. In both DBs the table names and structure are the same. Actually I have more DBs available with the same structure and the order of attaching seems to be the only thing I can relate to so far

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/36c1b/1). Please provide a [MCVE].